# Kali internet problems

Tags: kali-linux

I recently got Linux Kali 2 physically installed, how ever the internet is not working, when I try to write "fping google.com" for example it gets me "not reachable message", it for both wifi and eth, I tried to add the IP manually as well but it seems not working as well.

Comment: check for the kernel drivers for the NIC, `lspci -k`

Comment: Can you post the output of `ifconfig -a`? You need to run it as root.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue, on boot up, for some weird reason, my eth0 (primary network card) didnt pickup my DHCP settings either at all, or entirely. so much so, i got around it with this :

**ifconfig eth0 down**     <<< tear eth0 down/drop its current DHCP settings

**ifconfig eth0 up**       <<< bring it back up

**dhclient eth0**          <<< poll for new and complete DHCP settings which 
                               include the default gatway

I've even taken it 1 step further and added it to the Kali startup script in :

**/etc/rc.local**

you can either manually add the lines i highlighted bellow in bold BEFORE "exit 0", or just copy and past my scripts into the terminal command line

---

echo "#!/bin/sh -e" >

echo "#" >> /etc/rc.local

echo "# rc.local" >> /etc/rc.local

echo "#" >> /etc/rc.local

echo "# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel." >> /etc/rc.local

echo "# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other" >> /etc/rc.local

echo "# value on error." >> /etc/rc.local

echo "#" >> /etc/rc.local

echo "# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution" >> /etc/rc.local

echo "# bits." >> /etc/rc.local

echo "#" >> /etc/rc.local

echo "# By default this script does nothing." >> /etc/rc.local

echo "**ifconfig**" >> /etc/rc.local

echo "**ifconfig eth0 down**" >> /etc/rc.local

echo "**ifconfig eth0 up**" >> /etc/rc.local

echo "**dhclient eth0**" >> /etc/rc.local

echo "exit 0" >> /etc/rc.local